# Find the smallest set of values where at least one value is present in every row of a file

Tags: text-processing, numeric-data

I have a file `df` like:

```
1   4
1   6
1   7
1   10
2   3
2   9
2   10
3   4
4   7
9   10
```

I need to identify the smallest set of values such that every row in df contains at least one of these values.

From the above `df` the desired `out` is:

```
1
2
4
9
```

I have a process that works but is terribly slow. Is there a way I can execute this more quickly or parallelize the process?

```
x=1  
while [ $x -gt 0 ]  
do  
    i=$(paste df | tr '\t' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | 
        sort -r -k1,1 -k2,2n | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')  
    echo $i >> out  
    grep -vw $i df > tmpdf  
    cat tmpdf > df  
    x=$(paste df | wc -l)  
done
```

Comment: Would 1 2 4 10 be an acceptable solution?

Comment: due to the condition **at least one** - all values seem to be valid. Elaborate, why `7` should be ignored and `9` be in result?

Comment: You are looking for the strongly connected nodes in a connected undirected graph. Or something similar.

Comment: @icarus Yes, 1 2 4 10 would be fine. The current code just takes the lowest value when values are in equal abundance, but taking the highest would do fine.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I identify the most common value and use a subtractive process to find the next most common value. `1` appears 4 times, and then `2` appears 3 times. When rows containing `1` or `2` are removed, the next most frequently occuring value is `4`. Rows containing `4` are thus removed, which concomitantly removes `7`. The remaining row has value `9` and `10`. From here, because `9` and `10` are equally abundant, I choose the lowest value `9`, but as I mention to @icarus, taking the higher of equally abundant values would be fine.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed. I seek a disconnected graph while maintaining the largest possible number of nodes.

Comment: You can reduce the number of process required. Your use of paste is unconventional, most people would use cat, and then you would get a UUOC award. Some of your processing is much more expensive than it needs to be. For example in finding the thing to remove next you create a line for each field in the df file, sort this (an order n log n operation), then use uniq to count them, then another sort and an awk to print out the highest. You could do this all in awk without any sorting, just loop over the fields, and then at the end loop over your counts.

Comment: If you are looking for a representative from each strongly connected subgraph, then a search for Tarjan's algorithm and subsequent work will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some "line-noisy" perl:

```
perl -lane '
        for $f (@F) {push @{$x{$f}}, $.}                          # 1.
    } END {
        use List::Util qw/any first/;
        sub sort_by_count_desc {
            map  { $_->[0] } 
            sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] || $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } 
            map  { [$_, scalar(@{$x{$_}})] } 
            @_ 
        }
        @ordered = sort_by_count_desc(keys %x);                   # 2.
        %result = ();
        for ($i=1; $i<=$.; $i++) {                                # 3.
            $node = first { any {$_ == $i} @{$x{$_}} } @ordered;  # 4.
            $result{$node} = 1;
        }
        print join "\n", sort_by_count_desc(keys %result);
' df
```

Where

1. loops over the lines of the file and maps each value to the list of lines it appears on
2. creates an ordered line of the values sorted by the size of the list of appearances, descending
3. loops over the range of line numbers, and foreach line number
4. finds the first value for which the line number appears

This outputs

```
1
2
4
10
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tested this on a different dataset and it outputs a set of values greater than the minimal number required to disconnect all nodes.

Comment: Ah well. I did not follow a known algorithm with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a "dumb" *Linux* optimization using `bash`, but it's not especially portable and doesn't improve the algorithm:

```
f=$(mktemp) ; cp df $f
while [ -s $f ]  ; do   
    tr '\t' '\n' < $f | sort | uniq -c | sort -r -k1,1 -k2,2n | 
    grep -om1 '\S$' | tee >(grep -vwf - $f | sponge $f)
done
rm $f
```

Notes:

- Using the *df* input file as a scratchpad is bad practice, use `mktemp` instead.
- Output goes to *STDOUT*.  Change `done` to `done > out` if desired.
- The [`sponge`](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) util removes the need to name a *tmpdf* file.
- Uses `tee` and `grep -f -` instead of an `$i` search string variable.
- Checking  if `wc -l` is *0* isn't needed; `test -s` is sufficient.